# Cross-validating CSR, certificate, chain, and private key using PyOpenSSL

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

I'm new to using PyOpenSSL, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to programatically perform the following:

Verifying a cert against a chain:

```
openssl verify -CAfile "example.chain.crt" "example.crt"
```

Cross-validating among CSR, cert, and private key:

```
openssl req -noout -modulus -in example.csr | openssl md5
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in example.crt | openssl md5
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in example.key | openssl md5
```

I'm trying to see if I can do this from within the library, but I'm not seeing an easy way of doing this. My inexperience with SSL also makes it difficult. Anything obvious with PyOpenSSL that I'm missing in order to do the above checks?

I should also mention that I won't be using files directly, the CSR, cert, key, and bundle are entered as text into a form, which then requires validation. Therefore, I won't initially have any files on disk to use as arguments.